# gimp 2.8 cannot edit pdf file

Tags: 12.04, pdf, gimp

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and gimp2.8 installed.  It is working fine, but gimp2.8 cannot edit any pdf file (unknown file type).  This pdf files can be edited with gimp 2.6. I have installed 2.8 from the ppa:otto-kesselgulasch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why I do not know, but I had some libgimp stuff in usr/share/loca/lib .  After removing this gimp works fine and can import pdf files.